# Facebook fql query android

Tags: android, facebook-fql

I want to get friends list aswell as some fields like profile_pic,username etc.., for that am using

```
SELECT name,relationship_status,current_location 
         FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

Its returning, `<fql_query_response list="true"/>`

and no friend list is coming.

```
Edit: `"https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?&access_token="+accesstoken+"&query=SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1="+id+")";`
```

and passing that to this method:

```
public String request(String fql)  throws FileNotFoundException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
             Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
             parameters.putString("format", "json");
             parameters.putString("query", fql);
             parameters.putString("access_token",facebookClient.getAccessToken());

             if (facebookClient.isSessionValid()) {
                 parameters.putString("access_token",facebookClient.getAccessToken());
             }
                     String url = (fql != null) ? "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query" : "https://api.facebook.com/restserver.php";
             return Util.openUrl(url, "GET", parameters);
             }
```

but its returning 400 bad request? but when i run this url in browser its working correctly

What am doing wrong? Can anyone please give me piece of code to execute this query?

Thanks

Comment: query is ok. check what access token are you using

Comment: Am getting token from onComplete method by getusertoken method

Comment: Am getting response now when i entered in browser but its not executing in my query its returning bad request please my edited code about requesting..\

Comment: me() function to execute needs a valid access token, check if it is valid user token and where from you get it (SharedPreferences or authorization etc), try to put your uid instead of "me()" and see if it works.

Comment: please check my edited code: access token coming from facebookClient.getAccessToken();

Comment: check if yuor id is not empty, log the url before it executes.

Comment: the url returning correct values when i execute in browser, but its returning 400 bad request when executing with code android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it atlaasst, the thing is we have to encode the fql query before executing query.

Use this:

```
 public String request(String fql)  throws FileNotFoundException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
             Bundle parameters = new Bundle();

             if (facebookClient.isSessionValid()) {
                 //parameters.putString("access_token",facebookClient.getAccessToken());
             }
                     String url = (fql != null) ? "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?&access_token="+accesstoken+"&query="+URLEncoder.encode(fql) : "https://api.facebook.com/restserver.php";

                     System.out.println("url imple"+url);
                     return Util.openUrl(url, "GET", parameters);
             }
```